# How To Map EntitySet between tables using WebAPI

Tags: c#, sql, json, asp.net-web-api

Few of my tables have to access relationship data through tween tables, "Between Tables".

Example: I have an entity named Door, one named Hardware, and one named DoorHardware(DoorID int,HardwareID int)

I am using JSON to serialize data on the client and using the .net WebAPI to package it up into strongly typed objects. Everything is mapping correctly accept when I get to the situation where I need the Hardware EntitySet to be EntitySet and not EntitySet.

How do we tell WebAPI to get the Hardware from the JSON and not to look for DoorHardware, because my JSON is structured as expected. {door.hardware{}}... and not {door.doorHardware}

[image: SQL Tables]
Here is the .net WebAPI server side. You can see that door hardwares is what the EntitySet that is being used to for JSON to map to is DoorHardwares and not just Hardware.

[image: webAPI / JSON]

Answer (score 0):

Added a partial class in my linq to sql project and the webAPI maps the properties as expected.

```
 public partial class Door
    {
        public EntitySet<Hardware> Hardware{ get; set; }
    }
```